# Docker compose build always set ENV Value to port 80

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have following dockerfile:-

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/CustomerManagement/CustomerAPI/CustomerAPI.csproj", "src/CustomerManagement/CustomerAPI/"]

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/CustomerManagement/CustomerAPI"
RUN dotnet build "CustomerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -s https://www.myget.org/F/autoweb/api/v3/index.json

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CustomerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s --retries=1 CMD curl --silent --fail http://localhost:5000/hc || exit 1


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerAPI.dll"]
```

Docker.compose file:-

```
 customerapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}customerapi
    networks:
      - backendpool
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/CustomerManagement/CustomerAPI/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5000"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

Problem descriptions:-

I have instructed dockerfile to expose port 5000. When i tried to build the compose file its build fine but it never expose port 5000. When I checked my docker configuration, it always set to port 80:-

docker container image configuration:- pull through (docker inspect cli)

```
"DockerVersion": "19.03.1",                                                               
 "Author": "",                                                                             
 "Config": {                                                                               
     "Hostname": "",                                                                       
     "Domainname": "",                                                                     
     "User": "",                                                                           
     "AttachStdin": false,                                                                 
     "AttachStdout": false,                                                                
     "AttachStderr": false,                                                                
     "Tty": false,                                                                         
     "OpenStdin": false,                                                                   
     "StdinOnce": false,                                                                   
     "Env": [                                                                              
         "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",              
         "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",                                                    
         "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",                                               
         "ASPNETCORE_VERSION=2.2.6"                                                        
     ],                                                                                    
     "Cmd": null,                                                                          
     "Image": "sha256:1632908f5f238edcea0e99468a1584b859d6593bcd7e2a8943233c8d2bd4b983",   
     "Volumes": null,                                                                      
     "WorkingDir": "/app",                                                                 
     "Entrypoint": [                                                                       
         "dotnet",                                                                         
         "CustomerAPI.dll"                                                                         
     ],                                                                                    
     "OnBuild": null,                                                                      
     "Labels": null                                                                        
 },
```

No matter what value you set in ENV key-value pair, it never sets this way and m pretty much struggling to understand how to tell docker compose file to set ENV value to a expose port in docker file???

launch settings.json file:-

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "CustomerAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

docker-compose.local.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  customerapi:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

building my docker image container

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml build
```

Comment: ports:
      - "5000:5000"

Comment: It is already set in docker-compose.local.yml    version: '3.5'

services:
 
  customerapi:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

Comment: docker-compose -f docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml build

Comment: i can only see ports 5000 in your config

Comment: i have pasted launch settings.json can you check!!

Answer (score 2):

The correct sequence is this

```
FROM base AS final  

WORKDIR /app  

COPY --from=publish /app .  

EXPOSE 5000/tcp    

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, It works and It was utter painful, how is that it has order of precedence where as I have checked some of dockerfile config settings has port expose right after FROM.... therefore I thought it won't have any ordering issue where as compose file does have with its dependencies. I think docker folks has to work on it may be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the following environment variable inside the docker-compose file, in order to listen to the preferred port.

> ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

Answer (score -1):

Expose the port after the process finishes the multistage operation

```
FROM base AS final  

WORKDIR /app  

COPY --from=publish /app .  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerAPI.dll"]  

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
```

Comment: I think it should be like this                                                     FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .                                               
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerAPI.dll"]